# How to serialize an multiple dimensional array to string and the reverse?

Tags: jquery, serialization

I'm using jQuery.

[serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) seems not fit for this job.

Comment: Serialize to what?  XML, JSON, CSV, etc..

Comment: From an arbitrary object to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only serialisation on ‘arbitrary objects’ is `toString` as described by thenduks. This is a convenience serialisation for display purposes only (and even then very often generates useless string representations like `[object Object]`).

> Can this process be reversed?

Not reliably, no.

If the datatypes you need to serialise are just the JS builtins like Array, String, Number and unprototyped Object being used as a transparent mapping, you can use JSON. Call `JSON.stringify(obj)` to serialise, `JSON.parse(str)` to re-parse. Use [json2](http://www.json.org/js.html) or some other library with JSON features to support old browsers that don't have native JSON.

But ‘arbitrary objects’? No, can't be done (not in most other languages either).

Comment: I don't think it can't be done in most languages,because in PHP I can simply do it by $str = serialize($object); and $object = unserialize($str);

Comment: Not for ‘arbitrary objects’. There are unserialisable objects even for PHP.

Comment: OK,but in my case I just need it to work with multiple dimensional array.

Comment: But I'm already using jQuery,you mean I should pull another library?

Comment: Yes. It's a curious omission that jQuery has no JSON serialiser. (It can of course parse JSON just using `eval`.) See eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're looking for, if you just want the array represented as a string then you can call `toString`, which most types in javascript have defined:

```
>>> [1,2,3].toString()
"1,2,3"
```

Comment: Can this process be reversed?

Comment: The array can be multi-dimensional.

Comment: No. `['x,y', 'z']` ⇒ `x,y,z` ⇒ `['x', 'y', 'z']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`join()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) on your array to combine the elements into a string.  And [`split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) can be used to split a string into an array, with optional seperator and limit parameters.

Comment: and `split(',')` to reverse it (assuming no in-array strings used it).